# How to preg_match a PCRE expression?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
$key="`client` asc";
preg_match('
                ~(?J)
                    \s*
                    (?:`(?P<col>(?:[^`\\\\]|\\\\.|``)*)`|(?P<col>\S+))
                    (?:\s+(?P<dir>asc|desc))?
                    \s*
                \z~Axi', $key, $m);
print_r($m);
```

This regular expression fills the `col` key when tested here

https://regex101.com/r/i00sEn/1

It does not work correctly on my local `PHP 5.6` machine, or this `7.3` interpreter.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/915a26b741c6d086f21129f60af2420c74cf9f89

It works everywhere if I remove the backticks, but as the purpose of this code is to parse SQL ORDER BY clauses, I need the backticks.

Why does this work?  How can I get it to match backticks correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an alternation for both groups. What you might do using your pattern is to create a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|` instead of a non capturing group.

Thanks to the comment of [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) your pattern could look like:

```
(?J)
                    \s*
                    (?|`(?P<col>(?:[^`\\]|\\.|``)*)`|(?P<col>\S+))
                    (?:\s+(?P<dir>asc|desc))?
                    \s*
                \z
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i00sEn/3) | [Php demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5628da58e76bce547df4c78dab7e2b04fb66f843)

Comment: Thanks for solving my question, though can you tell me why it works on the regexp tester?

Comment: @dogsarecuttte Using the branch reset group makes the alternatives share the same capturing group. It works in the regex tester because you get one or the other due to the alternation. You can see the difference in group highlighting using `client asc` with and without the backticks using the 2 different patterns. See [demo1](https://regex101.com/r/mzHFE4/1) and [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/mzHFE4/2) If you check the pattern with the branch reset, you will see that with or without backticks, the group stays the same [demo3](https://regex101.com/r/mzHFE4/3)

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to branch reset is to use a conditional

```
 # http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/551b5ecba6d554cdeff616f193fca003cd777014

 (?xis-)
 \A                                    # BOS
 \s* 
 (?:
      ( `? )                                # (1), Optional backtick
      (?<col>                               # (2 start), Col body
           (?(?<= ` )                            # Conditional, is backtick behind ?
                (?: [^`\\] | \\ . | `` )*             # yes, match backtick body
             |  \S+                                   # no, match consecutive non-whitespaces
           )
      )                                     # (2 end)
      \1                                    # Backref to optional backtick
 )
 (?:                                   # Optional column direction 
      \s+ 
      (?<dir> asc | desc )                  # (3), ascending or descending
 )?
 \s* 
 \z                                    # EOS
```